# Data Collection and recording using Sensor Tags

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, texas-instruments

Hey i am quite new to using wearable sensors for data collection. I am using Sensor Tag from Texas Instruments.

I want to record the accelerometer, gyro and magnetometer and write the readings along with their time stamp in the connected android phones (phones are connected through Bluetooth).

Any literature or work in this direction and context will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

> Phones are connected through Bluetooth

I assume you are referring to a BLE-enabled smartphone and a SensorTag device. And, by *Bluetooth* you meant *Bluetooth Low Energy* interface.

First things first. You need to read a bit about how the SensorTag is programmed, when and why it needs to be programmed.

**How:** Using a CC Debugger. There is a lot of material available on TI website about them.

**When:** If you plan to reconfigure or add more services to the GATT structure, you need to do that in `gatt.xml` and download the generated `.hex` file into the SensorTag by means of the CC Debugger.

**Where this gatt.xml will be:** Pull out a sample project for SensorTag (de facto way of doing it) or any other sample project for BLE GATT Server device. I would recommend to do the former way than doing it the latter way, as there are other dependencies like `hardware.xml` and more, that can add into the need to study SensorTag.

**How to generate a .hex file:** BLEUpdate works hand-in-hand with CC Debugger. There are user manual available on TI website that helps you to get started with BLEUpdate and CC Debugger.

The next milestone you should look for is getting the SensorTag connected with the Smartphone application. With the TI sample application (I am not sure if there is any, but I expect that there has to be one) that can readily talk with SensorTag with its default (existing if you haven't already configured it) GATT configuration. So that is already achievable. If you happen to configure GATT structure, then you should first make sure that the SensorTag is still visible to the BLE-based applications. e.g. LightBlue.

---

> I want to record the accelerometer, gyro and magnetometer and write the readings along with their time stamp in the connected android phones.

Again, one assumption: I hope what you meant through *"...in the connected android phones."* is clear to you. FWIK, at a given instance a SensorTag can remain connected and send data to and receive from only one application (GATT Client). That virtual parallel connection with multiple applications is *virtual* in true sense.

Recording the data is never a big thing to achieve. Once the data is parsed in a proper way, it is no different in any of the use case. The easiest way to accommodate that data (records) will be a in .csv file (Many Android enthusiasts might have another easier option to suggest)